# Calculating big O swaps, calculations, and comparisons

Tags: algorithm, loops, time, complexity-theory, notation

Looking at the code below:

```
Algorithm sort

Declare A(1 to n)

n = length(A)

for i = 1 to n
    for j = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
       if A[i-1] > A[i] then
          swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
       end if
  next j
next i
```

## **I would say that there are:**

- 2 loops, both n, n*n = n^2 (n-1 truncated to n)
- 1 comparison, in the j loop, that will execute n^2 times
- A swap that will execute n^2 times
- There are also 2n additions with the loops, executing n^2 times, so 2n^2

## **The answers given in a mark scheme:**

**Evaluation of algorithm**

**Comparisons**

The only comparison appears in the j loop.
Since this loop will iterate a total of n^2
times, it will execute
exactly n^2

**Data swaps**

- There may be a swap operation carried out in the j loop.
- Swap( A[i-1], A[i] ) Each of these will happen n^2 times.
- Therefore there are 2n^2 operation carried out within the j loop
- The i loop has one addition operation incrementing i which happens n
  times
- Adding these up we the number of addition operations which is 2n^2 +
  n
- As n gets very big then n^2 will dominate therefore it is O(n^2)

NOTE: Calculations might include assignment operations but these will not affect overall time so ignore

## Marking overview:

- 1 mark for identifying i loop will execute n times.
- 1 mark for identifying j loop will execute 2n^2 times **Isn't this meant to be n*n = n^2? For i and j**
- 1 mark for correct number of calculations 2n^2 + n **Why is this not
  +2n?**
- 1 mark for determining that the order will be dominated by n^2 as n
  gets very big giving O(n^2) for the algorithm

## **Edit: As can be seen from the mark scheme, I am expected to count:**

- Loop numbers, but n-1 can be truncated to n
- Comparisons e.g. if statements
- Data swaps (counted as one statement, i.e. arr[i] = arr[i+1], temp = arr[i], etc. are considered one swap)
- Calculations
- Space - just n for array, etc.

**Could someone kindly explain how these answers are derived?**

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure where you got n^3 from, it's a bubble sort and runs in O(n^2). You'll have to fix your formatting to get an answer, it's not clear what you're asking. It doesn't really matter whether it's +n or +2n if you jut want the asymptotic complexity. If you're looking for the exact complexity, you'll have to choose what you're defining as a basic operation (probably swaps in this case)

Comment: The n^3 is given in a mark scheme. I'm also aware that you don't need the +n, etc. for the overall, but they are in the mark scheme. The first part is my take on it, the second is the mark scheme.

Comment: I'm pretty sure n^3 is wrong, you'll have to ask you teacher/ prof about that. (btw you can make headers in markdown with `#`, those might help you organize your question a bit better)

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully it's a bit clearer now

Comment: The n^3 looks like a simple typing error, as it's inconsistent with the rest of the text. Your teacher also seems to have forgotten about j's increments and probably also the comparison of i and j to n and n-1. And the inner loop runs n\*(n-1) times, not n\*n (or (n-1)*(n-1), that pseudo-code syntax is weird). Pointing out all the mistakes you and your teacher made probably won't make for a very good [so] answer. @user3080953 is right - we need to know what you're expected to count, as that decision would lead to very different constant factors.

Comment: The mark scheme is actually from an official examination board, unfortunately. Hopefully my edit has shone some light on my question. If there are mistakes in the markscheme - that is what is confusing me so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on the marking scheme, explicitly marking the operations they're counting. It seems they're counting assignments (but conveniently forgetting that it takes 2 or 3 assignments to do a swap). That explains why they count increment but not the `[i-1]` indexing.

#### Counting swaps

```
i loop runs n times
    j loop runs n-1 times (~n^2-n)
        swap (happens n^2 times)            n^2
```

#### Counting additions (`+=`)

```
i loop runs n times 
    j loop runs n-1 times (~n^2)
        increment j (happens n^2 times)     n^2
    increment i (happens n times)           n

sum:                                        2n^2 + n
```

Comment: This is actually incredibly helpful - the mark scheme had me on a skew for hours. Thank you very much!